# Entity Framework Core 1.0 PostgreSQL API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, asp.net-core

I'm trying to EF Core 1.0 with PostgreSQL with ASP.NET Core project, Here is my context class:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        :base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

I'm added the following packages:

```
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "type": "platform",
  "version": "1.0.0"
},
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
"Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
},
```

I've registered in `Startup.cs` as:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
                .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql("User ID=postgres;Password=;Server=localhost;Port=1234;Database=ApplicationDbContext;Pooling=true;"));

        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

Now when I try to add a migration as `dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigrations`, I get a successful migration message. But when I connect to the server in pgAdmin, I do not see any newly created database whats wrong, where I'm going things wrong?

Please also provide a link of 1-1 for using PostgreSQL with EFCore if you have any.

Comment: Does it work before adding a migration?

Comment: Have you also registered your service in `Startup.cs`?

Comment: No it does not worked at all, I'm trying this in Console App not in ASP.NET for learning.

Comment: @GeorgeChond I've updated the question for ASP.NET Core, can you please review it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a migration doesn't create a database or update it - it just creates the migration code in your project which is capable of bringing the database up to date. You may be looking for `dotnet ef database update`.

Read the [EFCore getting started docs](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/platforms/netcore/new-db-sqlite.html) carefully.

Comment: O I just forgot the basic. Thanks for reminding me back. Actually I'm still confronting a problem when I update the database and try to open it in pgAdmin, I get an error saying `invalid frontend message type 15, server terminated abnormally` Can you figure out the cause?

Comment: @JanshairKhan, I'd need more details for both problems in order to do anything. You should open issues for both.